# Creating a soap client in java given a WSDL file using WS-Policy

Tags: java, web-services, soap, soapui, soap-client

I am stuck where I have to Consume web service. When I send Request to server I got the below problem:

> SEVERE: WSP1007: Policy exception occurred when finishing WSDL parsing.
>   com.sun.xml.ws.policy.PolicyException: WSP0010: Unexpanded "POLICY_REFERENCE" node found referencing policy:X509TokenIntegrity-2.00

Does somebody know how to do this? thanks in advance

```
    <wsdl:operation name="sayHello">
        <soap:operation style="document" soapAction="sayHello"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:header message="tns:headerRequest" part="requestheader" use="literal"/>
            <soap:body parts="body" use="literal"/>
            <wsp:Policy>
                <wsp:PolicyReference URI="policy:X509TokenIntegrity-2.00"/>
                <wsp:PolicyReference URI="policy:X509TokenIdentificationWOTokenSignature-2.00"/>
            </wsp:Policy>               
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:header message="tns:headerResponse" part="responseheader" use="literal"/>
            <soap:body parts="response" use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
```

Comment: Please see if [this](https://java.net/projects/metro/lists/users/archive/2008-03/message/241) helps?

Comment: Thanks for your response, but in my case, in the WSDL i don't have for example:
       <s1:Policy s2:Id="X509TokenIntegrity-2.00">
               ....
        </s1:Policy>
I have only like you see in the above WSDL part